# SFML Views vs window confusion

Tags: c++, sfml

I have this single c++ / SFML code...

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#define windowWidth  600
#define windowHeight 300

int main()
{
   sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "SFML Views");

   sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight));
   view.zoom(2);
   window.setView(view);


   sf::RectangleShape back (sf::Vector2f(windowWidth, windowHeight));
   back.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

   sf::RectangleShape rect (sf::Vector2f(200, 100));
   rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
   rect.setPosition(windowWidth - rect.getSize().x, windowHeight - rect.getSize().y); // position in the lower right corner

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(back);
        window.draw(rect);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

...which might position the red rectangle in the lower right corner of the window.

However, when I zoom the view in (as in the code), it obviously moves along with the entire window like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSD3c.jpg).
I have some doubts:

1. To correct the positioning of the red rectangle and place it in the lower right corner of the global window, I currently have to do some calculations considering the zoom factor, original rectangle size, etc. Is there any easier way to position this rectangle in the lower-right corner of the global window?
2. How do I prevent some objects from being resized by the zoom of the view?
3. What do I have to do to have multiple active views in the same window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any easier way to position this rectangle in the lower-right corner of the global window?

From [SFML 2D camera tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-view.php): "To draw something using a view, you must draw it after calling the setView function of the target to which you are drawing"

So the drawing part should be

```
window.clear();
window.setView(view);
window.draw(back);
window.setView(window.getDefaultView()); //don't zoom red rect
window.draw(rect);
window.display();
```

> What do I have to do to have multiple active views in the same window?

Just call `setView()` for each active view and then drawing all the things in that view (again, if needed)

```
window.setView(leftHalfView);
window.draw(a);
window.draw(b);
window.draw(c);
window.setView(rightHalfView);
window.draw(a);
window.draw(b);
window.draw(c);
window.setView(minimap);
window.draw(a);
window.draw(b);
window.setView(window.getDefaultView());
window.draw(x);
window.draw(y);
```